# Enable Toggling for ToggleButton in the entire ControlTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf

In the `ControlTemplate` of the `ToggleButton`, I'm defining a `Border` which has a Polygon. The problem is that the EventTrigger is only applicable on the polygon, not the entire Border.

```wpf
<ToggleButton Padding="30, 10">
    <ToggleButton.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
            <Border Background="Red">
                <Polygon Points="12,12 12,26, 22,19" Fill="#4B86B1" Margin="0,0,5,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.6,0.5">
                    <Polygon.RenderTransform>
                        <RotateTransform x:Name="rotRect" Angle="0"/>
                    </Polygon.RenderTransform>
                    <Polygon.Effect>
                        <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0.5" Direction="0" Color="Black"  Opacity="1" BlurRadius="1"/>
                    </Polygon.Effect>
                </Polygon>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ToggleButton.Checked">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="rotRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle" From="0" To="90" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ToggleButton.Unchecked">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="rotRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle" From="90" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ToggleButton.Template>
</ToggleButton>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you wanted to just rotate the polygon around its center, get rid of the `RenderTransformOrigin` and instead set a `CenterX` and `CenterY` on your Transformation:

[image]

```xaml
<ToggleButton Margin="150,100">
    <ToggleButton.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                <Border Background="Red">
                    <Polygon Points="12,12 12,26, 22,19" Fill="#4B86B1" Margin="0,0,5,0">
                        <Polygon.RenderTransform>
                            <RotateTransform x:Name="rotRect" Angle="0" CenterX="17" CenterY="19"/>
                        </Polygon.RenderTransform>
                        <Polygon.Effect>
                        <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0.5" Direction="0" Color="Black"  Opacity="1" BlurRadius="1"/>
                    </Polygon.Effect>
                </Polygon>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ToggleButton.Checked">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="rotRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle" From="0" To="90" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ToggleButton.Unchecked">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="rotRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle" From="90" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ToggleButton.Template>
</ToggleButton>
```

---

If you really want to rotate the button too, simply move the Transformation to the border:

[image]

```xaml
<ToggleButton Margin="100">
    <ToggleButton.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
            <Border Background="Red">
                <Border.RenderTransform>
                    <RotateTransform x:Name="rotRect" Angle="0"/>
                </Border.RenderTransform>
                <Polygon Points="12,12 12,26, 22,19" Fill="#4B86B1" Margin="0,0,5,0">
                    <Polygon.Effect>
                        <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0.5" Direction="0" Color="Black"  Opacity="1" BlurRadius="1"/>
                    </Polygon.Effect>
                </Polygon>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ToggleButton.Checked">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="rotRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle" From="0" To="90" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ToggleButton.Unchecked">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="rotRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle" From="90" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ToggleButton.Template>
</ToggleButton>
```

Comment: But this rotates the border not the Polygon

Comment: @MohamedAhmed *"the problem is that the EventTrigger only applicable on the polygon, not the entire Border."* You said it's a problem that it only applies to the Polygon. Your current code only applies to the polygon. My example code here moves them together, isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: Isn't it possible that when the `ToggleButton` is toggled the Polygon only rotated

Comment: @MohamedAhmed That's exactly what currently happens. Your Margins are very weird, but your code matches your description. Could it be that you simply want to *"rotate the polygon around it's center"*?

Comment: One point, `RenderTransformOrigin` of the Border should be set to "0.5,0.5" for the polygon to looks it's rotating around its center , also it's interested that the Background of the Border should have a value for all this to work, I set it to Transparent so the Polygon _only_ rotates

Comment: @MohamedAhmed The RenderTransformOrigin is a *relative* size. Right now (as Mike already pointed out) your polygon takes up almost the entire space of the ToggleButton. If you fix your sizes and margins, then you can use a RenderTransformOrigin of `0.5, 0.5`. I have no idea what the second half of your comment means - the only reason you need a background is so that your ToggleButton is hit test visible (otherwise you can't click it).

Comment: FYI, your first code snippet doesn't seem to produce the results in your animated GIF (what tool do you use to create those those, btw?).  Maybe you went on to tweak the size or alignment but forgot to update your answer?

Comment: @MikeStrobel Oh, thanks for the hint - I forgot to remove the `RenderTransformOrigin` (just wrote it in the description but left it in). I'm using Microsoft Expression's Screen Capture and convert the video with PhotoShop.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your `Polygon` is actually quite larger than it appears; the horizontal and vertical alignment both default to `Stretch`, so even though the shape you define is relatively small, the `Polygon` is being laid out such that it fills your entire `Border` (less a 5pt margin on the right).

I would make two changes:

1. Set the horizontal and vertical alignments to `Left` and `Top`, respectively.
2. Get rid of the 12pt of 'empty' space inside the polygon, and shift them to the polygon's `Margin`.

```xml
<Polygon Points="0,0 0,14 10,7" Fill="#4B86B1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.6"
         Margin="12,12,5,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
  <Polygon.RenderTransform>
    <RotateTransform x:Name="rotRect" Angle="0" />
  </Polygon.RenderTransform>
  <Polygon.Effect>
    <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0.5" Direction="0" Color="Black"
                      Opacity="1" BlurRadius="1"/>
  </Polygon.Effect>
</Polygon>
```

I also generally use `Path` over `Polygon` (and most other `Shape` classes, except perhaps `Ellipse`).  I find it helps keep me reasonably fluent in the [Path Markup Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/path-markup-syntax), which is useful when I need to create more elaborate geometry.  An equivalent `Path` to your `Polygon` would be:

```xml
<Path Data="M 0,0 L 0,14 10,7 Z" ... />
```

It's up to you which to use.  One is not inherently 'better' than the other.

Comment: Thanks Mike, for the helpful answer